# get column names from a python dataframe having values as white spaces without using loops

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a below dataframe, I am trying to get the column names that has empty strings in a most efficient way. The dataframe looks like below after doing df.head().

```
id   type   check company  test
123   A     Soft             [[1649106820, 100029907158392,,,, 123]]                                
456   B     Hard    GMC      [[1649106812, 100029907158312,,,, 456]]
```

I am trying to do it without using loops or in an efficient way
Appreciate help with it

Expected output
{company,test}

Comment: Use the [`series.any()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) method.

Comment: Appreciate if you could share a prototype. Just wondering if how to get the column names using the above. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to find columns containing empty strings without testing individual value types:

```py
empty_cols = {col for col in df.columns if df[col].explode().explode().astype(str).str.strip().eq('').any()}
```

Output:

```
{'company', 'test'}
```

Explanation:

- use `explode()` twice to ensure we've unpacked values that are of type list of lists, such as those in column `test` in the question
- use `astype(str)` to convert numerical types to string, such as those in column `id`
- use `str.strip().eq('')` to get a boolean Series for a given column indicating whether a value (possibly unpacked) is an empty string (after stripping spaces)
- use `Series.any()` to reduce the boolean Series to a boolean value indicating whether the column has any empty strings
- use a set comprehension to get a set containing the labels of all columns that contain empty strings (including after unpacking list-of-list values).

Comment: Hi Thanks for the detailed answer, appreciate. Just checking, explode seems to be a costly operation as it would add more rows to the iteration.Can you pls clarify. TIA

Comment: It only adds more rows for column `test` in your example, and it allows for processing such exploded columns in the same simple way as a column of strings in the original input.

Comment: Quick question, can this be done without using Pandas, just trying to see if there is a more optimized way? TIA

Comment: Have you run any timing tests that make you believe the code in my answer is especially slow? You can compare it to the answer by @Barmar, which also seems like a reasonable approach, and choose the faster one.

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed answer. I am a newbie just trying to learn and understand if there is a different approach other than using pandas itself. This is just for my learning..TIA

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply()` to perform the test on all rows, then use `.any()` to test if it's true for any row.

```
def empty_val(val):
    if isinstance(val, list):
        return any(str(item).strip() == "" for item in val)
    else
        return str(item).strip() == ""

empty_cols = [col for col in df if df[col].apply(empty_val).any()]
```